# What are the maximum sizes of rectangle that can placed into elipse.?

Tags: real-analysis

please, I have got elipse which is definied $4x^2+9y^2=36$ and I should determine the sizes of $a,b$ so that the rectangle placed into elipse has maximum area. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of a rectangle inside a circle $4x^2+4y^2=36$ is a square $3\times3=9$.

$\therefore$ The maximum size of a rectangle inside an ellipse $4x^2+9y^2=36$ is a rectangle $3\times2=6$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

First note that a rectangle can be inscribed in an ellipse also if its sides are parallel to the symmetry axis.

Now,  a point $P$ on the ellipse has coordinates $P=(x_P,y_P)=(x,\pm\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{9-x^2})$. Chosing a point in the first quadrant, with $x_P>0$ and $y_P>0$ the area of the rectangle is $A=4x_Py_P$
so you have to find the maximum of the function:

$$
f(x)=\frac{8}{3} x\sqrt{9-x^2}
$$

can you do this?

Comment: Yes it is. 3/sqrt(2). But I do not know next steps.

Comment: Right! Substitute this value in $f(x)$ and you have the area. If you want the two sides $a,b$ of the rectangle, note that $a=2x_P$ and $b=2y_P$.

Comment: Please. I have got the area which is 12, but really struggle to find a and b. Please can you give me last hind. thanks a lot

Comment: I have the problem with the equation. The sizes should be sqrt(2)*3 and sqrt(2)*2. But do not know how to get there.

Comment: You have. $a=2\cdot \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}=3\cdot\sqrt{2}$ and $b=2\cdot \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{9-\frac{9}{2}}=\frac{4}{3}\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}=2\sqrt{2}$.